# How do I get to the same results as the Linux crypt and salt output?

Tags: hash, openssl, crypt

I used the following command on my Ubuntu machine "openssl passwd -crypt - salt pass book" to generate a salted password.

What hash is the output made up of? e.g SHA-512, MD5 etc. Also, i'm wondering how it's made up. For example, is it made by hashing "passbook" together?

I need more information on what hashing/algorithm is being used to generate the output I see.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result provided by the `openssl passwd` app when using the `-crypt` algorithm seems to be the same as the result provided by the Linux/Unix `crypt()` function. You can verify this with the following (quick'n'dirty) code snippet:

```
#include <crypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(
  int argc,
  char **argv)
{
  char *key = argv[1];
  char *salt = argv[2];
  char *enc = crypt(key, salt);
  printf("key = \"%s\", salt = \"%s\", enc = \"%s\"\n",
    key ? key:"NULL", salt ? salt:"NULL", enc ? enc:"NULL");
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./main book pass
key = "book", salt = "pass", enc = "pahzZkfwawIXw"
$ openssl passwd -crypt -salt pass book
pahzZkfwawIXw
```

The exact details of how the `crypt()` function seem to be explained most clearly in [its OSX man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/3/crypt/), in particular:

```
Traditional crypt:
  The first 8 bytes of the key are null-padded, and the low-order 7 bits of each character is
  used to form the 56-bit DES key.

  The salt is a 2-character array of the ASCII-encoded salt.  Thus, only 12 bits of salt are
  used.  count is set to 25.

Algorithm:
  The salt introduces disorder in the DES algorithm in one of 16777216 or 4096 possible ways
  (ie. with 24 or 12 bits: if bit i of the salt is set, then bits i and i+24 are swapped in
  the DES E-box output).

  The DES key is used to encrypt a 64-bit constant, using count iterations of DES.  The value
  returned is a null-terminated string, 20 or 13 bytes (plus null) in length, consisting of
  the salt, followed by the encoded 64-bit encryption.
```